# Oracle query to display 2 sum fields from same column and calculated on different field conditions from different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below 2 tables and I have to, write a query to display the sum of the total amount received through the credit card and cheque. Give the alias names as 'total_credit' and 'total_cheque' respectively.

table_payment
id (PK)
user_id
amount
transaction_type_id (FK)

table_transaction_type
id (PK)
type

Expected Output:

```
total_credit| total_cheque     
Value a     | Value B
```

I tried with below query but I getting values in different rows

```
select  sum(case when tt.type = 'Credit Card' then pt.amount end) as
"total_credit",  sum (case when tt.type = 'Cheque' then pt.amount end)
as "total_cheque" from payment pt join transaction_type tt on
pt.transaction_type_id = tt.id group by tt.type
```

Actual_Output:

```
total_credit| total_cheque     
Value A     |     
            | Value B
```

not sure how to get Value B in first row along with Value A, please advice.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking to do is "pivot" the data, and Oracle provides a pivoting function:

```
WITH 
   T 
AS 
(
   select tt.type, pt.amount
     from payment pt
     join transaction_type tt on tt.id = pt.transaction_type_id
)
SELECT 
   *
FROM 
   T
PIVOT 
(
   SUM(amount) 
   FOR 
      (type) 
   IN 
      ('Credit Card', 'Cheque')
);
```

Further examples can be found here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pivot_examples.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id, sum(case when tt.type='Credit Card' the amount end) as total_credit, sum(case when tt.type='Cheque' the amount end) as total_credit 
from table_payment p
inner join table_transaction_type tt
on p.transaction_type_id = tt.id
group by user_id;
```

Comment: It looks like you decided to change the table names (`table_cheque` isn't a table in his original question.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  (SELECT sum(pt.amount FROM from payment pt 
join transaction_type tt on pt.transaction_type_id = tt.id 
WHERE tt.type = 'Credit Card'
group by tt.type) as "total_credit"
, (SELECT sum(pt.amount FROM from payment pt 
join transaction_type tt on pt.transaction_type_id = tt.id 
WHERE tt.type = 'Cheque'
group by tt.type) as "total_cheque"
```

I considered using it as two sub queries, but it looks like we're not joining on any other ID or anything.

Full disclosure: I'm not familiar with Oracle, but this query will definitely work in T-SQL, and I believe it would work in MySQL, so I don't see why it wouldn't work in Oracle, too.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just add a max to it?

```
  SELECT MAX (SUM (CASE WHEN tt.TYPE = 'Credit Card' THEN pt.amount END))
             AS "total_credit",
         MAX (SUM (CASE WHEN tt.TYPE = 'Cheque' THEN pt.amount END))
             AS "total_cheque"
    FROM payment pt JOIN transaction_type tt ON pt.transaction_type_id = tt.id
GROUP BY tt.TYPE
```

here is a sample with fake data you can run in oracle.

```
WITH
    transaction_type
    AS
        (SELECT 1 id, 'Credit Card' AS TYPE FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'Cheque' FROM DUAL),
    payment
    AS
        (SELECT 500 AS amount, 1 AS transaction_type_id FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 300, 2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 200, 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 400, 2 FROM DUAL)
  SELECT MAX (SUM (CASE WHEN tt.TYPE = 'Credit Card' THEN pt.amount END))
             AS "total_credit",
         MAX (SUM (CASE WHEN tt.TYPE = 'Cheque' THEN pt.amount END))
             AS "total_cheque"
    FROM payment pt JOIN transaction_type tt ON pt.transaction_type_id = tt.id
GROUP BY tt.TYPE
```

result

```
 total_credit total_cheque
 700          700
```

Comment: Far too complicated! Just drop the GROUP BY clause in the original query - that's all that is needed.

Comment: I thougt SUM whas what was required not MAX ?!

Answer (score 0):

don't group by `tt.type` - that is why you get that result. If you need to group by `user_id` (as in one of the solutions) then do; if you need a result with exactly one row and two columns, aggregated (summed) over all users, don't group by ANYTHING, you don't need a GROUP BY clause. (I believe the SQL Standard doesn't allow that; Oracle definitely does, but if that bothers you, you can add something trivial, like GROUP BY NULL.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the code without group by clause

```
select  sum(case when tt.type = 'Credit Card' then pt.amount end) as
total_credit,  sum (case when tt.type = 'Cheque' then pt.amount end)
as total_cheque from payment pt join transaction_type tt on
pt.transaction_type_id = tt.id
```